# SMS app for Android that allows deleting a message or thread in one step

Tags: android, sms

I have tried several texting applications and most require at least 3 steps to delete individual messages. I often receive several notification/ announcement type messages that I want to delete as soon as I read them. I don't want to delete entire threads but just need a way to quickly delete a message after reading it although deleting thread would be awesome too.

BUT my main need is to be able to do it quickly, like in 1 or 2 button-presses. The apps I've tried (textra, messaging etc) require a long-press to select and then a couple more steps to select the delete option from the menu and then a confirmation pop-up to acknowledge all of which is too much to deal with for 1 SMS.

This is painful enough to make me post this question :). So if you know of an app or a solution that will help me delete in 1 or 2 steps max, please let me know.